# Angular: Bootstrap: Form field style

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to build a form validation with Bootstrap in Angular.

Which CSS style shall I use to mark error fields?

I need to paint error fields with red background or similar.

Here is the repo:

https://github.com/VictorDDT/test07-form-mdbootstrap

[image]

Comment: So are you asking how to dynamically add a css class to your input fields, or are you asking for styling advice? What have you tried so far?

Comment: checkout this article: https://medium.com/swlh/angular-validation-errors-made-easy-3bc1a837c6e7